# PageSpeed "Enable Compression" in web application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jboss7.x, pagespeed

I did the Pagespeed of my application in the chrome browser.Page score is 30 out of 100. Resulted couple of errors, out of few results. I am facing trouble in fixing the "Enable compression" for js and css.

I am using Spring MVC and jboss 7.1.1. I tried some configuration changes in the jboss standalone xml, but not worked.

```
<system-properties>
        <property name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION" value="on"/>
        <property name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION_MIME_TYPES" value="application/javascript,text/javascript,text/css,text/html,text/xml,text/json"/>
    </system-properties>

<script type="application/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/dashboard-assets/scripts/daterangepicker.js"></script>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: _"I tried some configuration changes"_ Such as ...?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, updated the configuration changes which i did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Check for the correct Mime-Type.

Your are using mine types to select which files get compressed. Have a look if these match up with the ones you are actually serving. This is available in the Chrome Network tab (or similar if using a different Browser)

Mime Types from my Project are

```
text/xml text/plain text/css text/javascript application/json application/javascript application/xml image/svg+xml
```

Note that for JavaScript it is actually application/javascript.

## Serve Assets from a Webserver

Depending of your setup you should have a look at serving assets (like images, js, css, fonts etc) from a Web Server like nginx or Apache httpd. These web servers are more capable of handling static files and it also means less traffic is sent to your application server.

Comment: Can you support your claims that httpd is always faster than JBoss? At least for Tomcat that doesn't seem to be true: http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2010/03/24/myth-or-truth-one-should-always-use-apache-httpd-front-apache-tomcat-improve-perform

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it's not possible to change the server right away.

Comment: My Script: <script type="application/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/dashboard-assets/scripts/daterangepicker.js"></script>

Comment: Still facing similar error, standalone xml <system-properties>
        <property name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION" value="on"/>
        <property name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION_MIME_TYPES" value="application/javascript,text/javascript,text/css,text/html,text/xml,text/json"/>
    </system-properties>

Comment: @StefanHaberl Thanks for the link, very interesting read. I did not claim that webservers are always faster, I just said they are more capable of handling static files. This means many things, including but not limited to caching, ease of scaling and having less requests hitting the application server.

Comment: _"more capable of handling static files"_ Can you provide any proof for your claim?